# Why is my V8 build failing on Ubuntu on AWS with a message about a google storage file not existing?

Tags: v8

I am attempting to build V8 on Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS by executing the following commands. These are lines from a Makefile, which is why the syntax is unusual.

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git depot_tools
(export PATH=$(shell pwd)/depot_tools:$$PATH && fetch v8)
(cd v8 && git checkout -b 3.31.30 --quiet)
(export PATH=$(shell pwd)/depot_tools:$$PATH && cd v8 && gclient sync)
(export PATH=$(shell pwd)/depot_tools:$$PATH && cd v8 && make x64.release -j8 library=shared)
```

However, on line 2 (running `fetch v8`), the process fails with the following error message.

```
[10:11:36][Step 1/1]      [exec] (export PATH=/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8/depot_tools:$PATH && fetch v8)
[10:12:54][Step 1/1]      [exec] 
[10:12:54][Step 1/1]      [exec] ________ running '/usr/bin/python v8/build/landmines.py' in '/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8'
[10:12:54][Step 1/1]      [exec] Clobbering due to missing landmines file.
[10:12:54][Step 1/1]      [exec] 
[10:12:54][Step 1/1]      [exec] ________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=win32 --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/win/clang-format.exe.sha1' in '/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8'
[10:12:55][Step 1/1]      [exec] 
[10:12:55][Step 1/1]      [exec] ________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=darwin --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/mac/clang-format.sha1' in '/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8'
[10:12:55][Step 1/1]      [exec] 
[10:12:55][Step 1/1]      [exec] ________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format.sha1' in '/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8'
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] Error: Command download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format.sha1 returned non-zero exit status 1 in /var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] File gs://chromium-clang-format/7219213d084db0ea8eaed8f4291814f4f46fad3a for v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format does not exist.
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] 0> File gs://chromium-clang-format/7219213d084db0ea8eaed8f4291814f4f46fad3a for v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format does not exist, skipping.
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]   {
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     "managed": False,
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     "name": "v8",
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     "custom_deps": {},
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     "deps_file": "DEPS",
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     "safesync_url": "",
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]   },
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] ]
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] '
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] Traceback (most recent call last):
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]   File "/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 335, in <module>
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     sys.exit(main())
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]   File "/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 330, in main
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     return run(options, spec, root)
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]   File "/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 324, in run
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     return checkout.init()
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]   File "/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 136, in init
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]   File "/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 76, in run_gclient
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]   File "/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 66, in run
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     return subprocess.check_call(cmd, **kwargs)
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec]     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('gclient', 'sync', '--with_branch_heads')' returned non-zero exit status 2
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] make[3]: Leaving directory `/var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8'
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] make[3]: *** [checkout] Error 1
[10:12:56][Step 1/1]      [exec] make[2]: *** [v8.build] Error 2
```

This same process works fine on a local virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04. The build fails running on an instance running on AWS EC2, also running Ubuntu 14.04, where the build is executing under JetBrains TeamCity.

The key error seems to be this line:

```
Error: Command download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format.sha1 returned non-zero exit status 1 in /var/teamcity/work/efeb1dfa99775e78/libs/3rdParty/v8
```

What is this error trying to tell me? What am I doing wrong? Google revealed one other user with [a similar problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/v8-users/9BTtrP26DSs/Dft5MhUrfIkJ), but no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case my continuous integration/teamcity user did not have a "home" directory. I defined one as follows, and the issue was resolved.

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/teamcity/home
sudo usermod --home /var/teamcity/home teamcity
sudo chown -R teamcity:teamcity /var/teamcity
```

Comment: May you explain it more? I have same problem but I am newbie in Linux too.

Comment: @user145959 I was running as a user account for which a "home" directory was not properly defined. "Usermod" fixes this issue. Might be different on other distros, YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error here with arch linux(64)

In my case it was possible to ignore this error when making just the 32 bit version. -> make ia32.release

you can try to add make ia32.release GYPFLAGS=-Dclang=0 if clang brings up errors

Hope that helps a little bit!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment, I'll try that and see if it gives me any more information.